# Make click in a button in html form with webBrowser controll in C# without make click just automatic

Tags: c#, html, forms, post, submit

I want make submit in this page http://www.enviarsmsacuba.com/?p=join with C# and webbRowser controll but i can not . I search in this site but im try the other things but i cant do. Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Maybe we can build on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it because you need a human every time you tell the WebBrowser control to submit the form.
I'm pretty sure you can see the captcha implementation in this website. Every time this will be different. If you dont enter the right letters it will never be submitted.

Comment: I know how i can do that, setting the focus in the button and later simulate click in the button, that can make with sendKey in C#. So its possible.

Comment: this is the answer

 mshtml.IHTMLControlElement button = (mshtml.IHTMLControlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Submit").DomElement;
                button.focus();

                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");